# How to obtain the order in which tests are executed when running RSpec with --order random?

Tags: rspec

I am running my test cases with `--order random`. I have 3 different test cases, with the names of "a", "b" and "c". After executing rspec, it is showing the seed it used for that specific sequence. How can I know the test name sequence of a-b-c or b-c-a or c-a-b, etc... with the seed value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `rspec` with a verbose format:

```
rspec --order random --format documentation
```

It will print all of the example descriptions as well as the seed.

There are `html` and `json` output formats as well, which also include the test names and so will tell you the order.

If you prefer brevity, `-f d` is the same as `--format documentation` and so on.